# I try to switch a specific struct by creating an int of it and can't find a fault

Tags: c, struct

I defined this structure:

```
struct Command_Type {
                       uint8_t A,B,Command;
}; // struct Command_Type
```

and some constants like:

```
#define _HeartBeat ((struct Command_Type) {0x10,0x01,0})
```

I did use it in some funktions and could as well use it how I wanted to do but now I want to do a switch funtion where the case should use the labels. There for I defined a int_of_Command_Type as this:

```
#define int_of_Command_Type(A) ((unsigned int) (((int) ((A).A)) << 16) |\
                                (unsigned int) (((int) ((A).B)) << 8) | \
                                (unsigned int) (((int) ((A).Command))))
```

when I use this function to print out an %u value from a Variable of type struct Command_Type it works perfect.

now I did want to do something like this:

```
struct Command_Type Command_type_var=_HearBeat;

 ....some code ....

switch(Command_type_var)
{
  case inf_of_Command_Type(_HeartBeat):  .....
                                        break;
  default: 
};
```

and I get the following fault message: case label does not reduce to an integer constant. Does someone know, how I can get round that problem with an easy way, because I do not understand at all what is wrong when it works for testprints and only not in the case label position. I've got lots of defined commands and don't want to change all of them but anyway I don't understand how I could handle it. Maybe with (const int) or what ever is needed?

Hope anyone does know quick what is really the fault and if there is a way round.

Comment: Any reason you use a macro instead of the `const` variable? General advise is not to use macros if you don't need to. The other macro also looks suspectible. Do you have adversries against automatic type-checking?

Comment: Suggest you use an `if` block instead of a `switch`. `_HeartBeat` is not an integer constant by definition (it is of type `struct Command_Type`). So none of its fields can be used to produce the value for a `case` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The constraint of the `switch` statement is that it requires according to C11 standard an integer expression::

> **6.8.4.2/1** The controlling expression of a switch statement shall have integer type.

`Command_type_var` doesn't match this constraint, as it is a struct (even if the struct holds in an integer,  and even if you would hold only integer bit fields).

**How to solve it:**

It's quite simple: convert your struct to an int in the switch, by using your macro:

```
switch(int_of_Command_Type(Command_type_var))  // here we use an int
{
case int_of_Command_Type(_HeartBeat):  // this is fortunately a constant
      break;
default: 
      break; 
};
```

Of course, this works only if the macro is defined correctly:  the parameter can't take the name of one of the struct member, or otherwhise you'll end up with weird errors due to unexpected substitutions (the A parameter should be renamed X):

```
#define int_of_Command_Type(X) ((unsigned int) (((int) ((X).A)) << 16) |\
                               (unsigned int) (((int) ((X).B)) << 8) | \
                               (unsigned int) (((int) ((X).Command))))
```

**[Live demo](http://ideone.com/ReCG7C)**

***Edit:*** If, despite the fact that `int_of_Command_Type(_HeartBeat)` could be calculated at compile time, your compiler doesn't recognize it as a constant integer expression, you should replace  the switch with if/else sequences.  This is the case for MSVC 2015, who seems to use the stricter rules of 6.6/6 that do not require the implementation to provide for the possibility to use the `.` operator on structure constants.

Comment: Thanks, I did use sed Commands to exchange all constants of Comand_Type and got it working. It helped me that it is not possible to do so. Sorry for my typing fault - to forget the function int_of_Command_Type to use. In my Problem I used it proper. So now it works with switch as I did define all the commands as an int and every where to set up the struct I used shift operations and Bitwise And.